# Potential problems with casting IQueryable<T> to IAsyncEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After reading [this article](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233659-do-not-await-what-does-not-need-to-be-awaited) on excessive `await` usage I decided to remove awaiting where possible. This lead to an issue with my data services because of two reasons:

1. All methods that retrieve collection return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` by convention
2. EF does not provide `ToEnumerableAsync`.

Now when I remove `await` the compiler no longer unfolds `Task` objects and I am left with compilation error which says that `Task<List<T>>` cannot be converted to `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`.

So I set out to create my own `ToEnumerableAsnyc`. The "PoC" version looked like this:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerableAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    => (await source.ToListAsync()).AsEnumerable();
```

However this only wraps the extra `await` and does not remove it, i.e. there is still my `await` and the one used internally from `ToListAsync`. To my understanding from the above linked article this generates unnecessary overhead. It's not signifficant, but is an overhead none the less. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

So I set out to find how Microsoft devs went about to implement `ToListAsync` in **ASP.NET Core 2.2** and I managed to create my own implementation of `ToEnumerableAsync`, which does not use `await` based on their solution. That's how it looks:

```cs
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> ToEnumerableAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    var asyncEnum = AsAsyncEnumerable(queryable);
    var list = new List<T>();

    return asyncEnum.Aggregate(
        (IEnumerable<T>)list,
        (list, x) =>
        {
            ((List<T>)list).Add(x);
            return list;
        });
}

private static IAsyncEnumerable<T> AsAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    if (queryable is IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable)
    {
        return asyncEnumerable;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"Cannot cast \"IQueryable\" to \"IAsyncEnumerable\". Type: \"{typeof(T).FullName}\"");
}
```

And finally to my question: What can go wrong with the cast of `IQueryable<T>` to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` that the devs put explicit `InvalidOperationExeption`? How and why can an `IQueryable<T>` fail to cast to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?

Original EF file: [QueriableExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore/Extensions/Internal/QueryableExtensions.cs).

Comment: Here is  [a better article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: The one you quoted is a being little dramatic about nanoseconds in a chain that ususally will do some I/O (many milliseconds) in the end.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thank you, that was informative read. In my case I am only concerned with Exception raising, but I don't think it would make it harder to see the point of origin of the Exception if it is thrown on the spot. And I am aware that its very small optimization.